# How to save image in ms access and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hi please can anyone help me on how to save image in ms access and vb.net ? it keep saying the data type mismatch in criteria expression, by the way here is my source code.

```
Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(PHOTOPictureBox.Image)
Try 
   bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
   bytImage = ms.ToArray()
   ms.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
strsql = "insert into request (FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, QLFR, ALIAS, DATEOFBIRTH, AGE, PLACEOFBIRTH, BARANGAY, TOWN, PROVINCE, GENDER, CIVILSTATUS, CITIZENSHIP, CONTACTNUMBER, PHOTO)values(@a0,@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8,@a9,@a10,@a11,@a12,@a13,@14,@a15)"
acscmd.CommandText = strsql
acscmd.Connection = acsconn
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a0", FIRSTNAMETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", MIDDLENAMETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", LASTNAMETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", QLFRComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", ALIASTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", DATEOFBIRTHDateTimePicker.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", AGETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", PLACEOFBIRTHTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a8", BARANGAYComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a9", TOWNTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a10", PROVINCETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a11", GENDERComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a12", CIVILSTATUSComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a13", CITIZENSHIPTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a14", CONTACTNUMBERTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a15", bytImage)
acscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
acscmd.Dispose()
MsgBox("ADDED")
print.Show()
```

Comment: What datatype you have created for photo in MS Access

Comment: OLE OBJECT but i do not know why it keep saying data type mismatch in criteria expression vb.net

Comment: Can you post the exact error and full code

Comment: OledbException Unhandled

Comment: datatype mismatch in criteria expression when i click the save button

Comment: AddWithValue creates parameter looking at the datatype of the value. So it is really easy to create a parameter of the wrong type when you pass all Text values. In particular Date fields and floating point fields are very prone to raise errors of that type when you pass texts for them

Comment: the only problem in that is the picture

Comment: Are you sure that it's for that column? I can see at least one other candidate where you're using the `Text` of a `DateTimePicker` instead of the `Value`.

Comment: What happens if you remove the Image field and its parameter from your query? Do you get the same exception?

Comment: no didnt get any error if i remove the image field and its parameter

Comment: @ArvinLagundayDayro Can you show me the bytImage declaration?

Comment: @VigneshKumarA Dim bytImage() As Byte

Answer (score 0):

There is minor mistake while assigning 14th parameter. you have missed `a` in it. It may or may not help you, since you have problem with 15th parameter.

Can you please make sure that, you have declared bytImage as follows

```
Dim bytImage() As Byte
Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(PHOTOPictureBox.Image)
Try 
   bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
   bytImage = ms.ToArray()
   ms.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
strsql = "insert into request (FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, QLFR, ALIAS, DATEOFBIRTH, AGE, PLACEOFBIRTH, BARANGAY, TOWN, PROVINCE, GENDER, CIVILSTATUS, CITIZENSHIP, CONTACTNUMBER, PHOTO)values(@a0,@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8,@a9,@a10,@a11,@a12,@a13,@a14,@a15)"
acscmd.CommandText = strsql
acscmd.Connection = acsconn
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a0", FIRSTNAMETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", MIDDLENAMETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", LASTNAMETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", QLFRComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", ALIASTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", DATEOFBIRTHDateTimePicker.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", AGETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", PLACEOFBIRTHTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a8", BARANGAYComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a9", TOWNTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a10", PROVINCETextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a11", GENDERComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a12", CIVILSTATUSComboBox.SelectedItem)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a13", CITIZENSHIPTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a14", CONTACTNUMBERTextBox.Text)
acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a15", bytImage)
acscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
acscmd.Dispose()
MsgBox("ADDED")
print.Show()
```

Comment: I don't think that that would actually make a difference, given that parameters are positional rather than named for Access anyway. If that was the issue, there would be a different error message.

Comment: i already declare the dim bytimage () as byte in the public class form

Comment: it says variable bytimage has been used before it was assigned to value this will cause run time error

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your code specifically but I just added a an OLE Object column to an existing test MDB database I have and ran the code below and the record saved without issue:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
            If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                PictureBox1.ImageLocation = ofd.FileName
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim pictureData As Byte()

        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            pictureData = ms.ToArray()
        End Using

        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdb"";Persist Security Info=True"),
            command As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Person (FullName, DateOfBirth, Picture) VALUES (@FullName, @DateOfBirth, @Picture)",
                                        connection)
            With command.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBox1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
                .AddWithValue("@Picture", pictureData)
            End With

            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'd suggest rewriting the code and following the format that I have and just see whether the issue goes away.